# Present simple or Future simple to answer question about schedule

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I learned that we should use present simple to talk about schedules. However, if people were to ask me when will my flight leave. How should I respond?

A. My flight will leave at 1:00 pm.

B. my flight leaves at 1:00 pm.

This question is too specific that I can only ask with an example, so I could not find it anywhere on the internet.

Where I learned: https://youtu.be/Z19NAX_gWxI at 8:20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean the same here, it's just a matter of choice.

For present simple, apart from the usage for **"the present"**, such as facts, habits, temporary situations... etc, we can also use it for **"the future"**.

We use the present simple to talk about the future when we are discussing a timetable or a fixed plan.

For instance:

> - What time does the show start?
> - The train arrives at eight.
> - School starts at 7 o'clock. Don't be late!

We can use *"will"* to talk about future facts.

For instance:

> - The sun will rise at 6:40 tomorrow.
> - The prize will be given to the best player.
> - I will not discuss anything related to politics or religion.

In your example, the flight departure time is both a fixed timetable and a future fact, thus both ways are acceptable.

**P.S.** There are many different ways to express the same thing.

> 1. My flight *will leave* at 1:00 pm.
> 2. My flight *leaves* at 1:00 pm.
> 3. My flight *is leaving* at 1:00 pm.
> 4. My flight *is going to leave* at 1:00 pm.

#### Sources

["The train will leave" vs. "is going to leave" vs. "leaves" vs. "is leaving"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59292/the-train-will-leave-vs-is-going-to-leave-vs-leaves-vs-is-leaving) from [ELU Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/)

[Using the Future Simple Tense](https://www.oysterenglish.com/future-simple-tense.html) from [Oyster English](https://www.oysterenglish.com/)

[When Should I Use The Present Simple Tense?](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-simple-use.html) from [Perfect English Grammar](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/)